# Flash AS3 TouchEvent and MouseEvent conflict

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 2 controllers on my stage, one behaves like an analog controller (A) for left/right up/down etc, controlled with a TouchEvent. The firing controller (B) is bound to another TouchEvent.

The problem is TouchEvent seems to be much slower than using say MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN for controller (B) which results in a much faster firing mechanism. If I am using TouchEvent to control (A), and MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN on controller (B), (B) will not fire unless I release (A) meaning I cannot move and shoot at the same time which is frustrating, but I can use a MouseEvent for controller (A) and a TouchEvent for controller (B). Any ideas how I can stop the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PressAndTapGestureEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/PressAndTapGestureEvent.html).

Comment: Worth a shot but seems to simulate a double click? For the time being I have introduced 2 firing buttons side by side so you can effectively tap with 2 fingers doubling the firing speed.